# webdriver-manager start: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: protractor

I am configurating protractor environment by the  http://www.protractortest.org/#/ website.When execute

> webdriver-manager start

```
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.255.116:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

But sometimes,it will execute success.
The environment is:
Protractor –version:5.2.0
Java –version:1.8.0_131
Node –v:v8.9.0
Npm –v:5.5.1

Can someone please telling me what is happening here. Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more information. It should not be related to `webdriver-manager start` `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.255.116:443` this is more related to your test because selenium starts locally. Have you tried `webdriver-manager update` ?

Comment: Yes. I has execute the webdriver-manager update.But sometimes,it will timeout downloading.As show below:       [19:50:15] E/downloader - Connection timeout downloading: https://github.com/moz
illa/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.19.1/geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.zip. Defaul
t timeout is 4 minutes.

Comment: I think the problem is related to your internet connection... is it stable enough ? May be you are working under VPN ?

Comment: Because my country can't use google.So I download the Lantern agency...

Comment: I would suggest go for selenium grid in this case, There might be a chances that webdriver-manager access some repo internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a VPN, you may need to add a proxy.

```
> set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.host.blah:80
> set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.host.blah:80
> webdriver-manager start
```

This worked for me anyway.