# Protractor installed in offline mode - error for webdriver-manager start - what am I doing wrong

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I need to install and use Protractor / Selenium on the machine without Internet access.

To do that, I've tried to download all needed files and copy them to the destination machine.

---

**On my machine (with Internet access)**

I installed [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) and Selenium webdriver with the following command:

```
npm install -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
```

---

**On destination machine (without Internet access)**

I copied *all* files from the location returned by `npm config get prefix` to the computer without Internet access.

Then I executed following command on the machine without Internet access:

`npm --cache-min 9999999 install -g protractor`

which seems to succeed.

However, when I try to execute `webdriver-manager start` command, I receive following error message:

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
>   chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443
>       at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)

I receive the same error when executing `webdriver-manager update` (as in this case: [webdriver-manager start: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710023/webdriver-manager-start-error-connect-etimedout))

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? How should I properly setup Protractor and webdriver on the machine without Internet access?

Comment: Are your machine running under any proxy ?

Answer (score 2):

Because `webdriver-manager start` will look up the latest version number of selenium-server.jar and webdriver binaries through internet no matter they are already exists on local.

But `webdriver-manager` not supply cmd option to disable the looking up.

The quick way is to run the java cmd behind `webdriver-manager start` directly to skip the looking up.

> java
>   -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Tools\npm-global\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.38.exe
>   -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Tools\npm-global\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.20.1.exe
>   -jar C:\Tools\npm-global\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar
>   -port 4444

The complex way is to change `webdriver-manager` code or setup a mirror on local and use cmd option: `--alternate_cdn` and point it to your local mirror url. ( I didn't verify this can work, get it after read some source code)

Comment: If we use `directConnect`, it should overcome starting the `webdriver-manager` right?

Comment: @demouser123, you are right. When `directConnect = true`, protractor will launch an chromedriver binary automatically before all.  The binary running progress will start a http server with address like `http://localhost:34562` (the port is random),  and tests will use this address as seleniumAddress

Comment: @yong It seems to work, but I wonder if there's a way to `nicely` close/quit/shutdown the selenium server, the counterpart of `webdriver-manager shutdown` command?